# Minimum, mean and maximum distance between points 3-D in Python

Tags: python, performance, optimization, computational-geometry, euclidean-distance

I have a list of x,y,z points. Using the formula to find the distance between two points in 3-D

```
import math
import numpy as np

point0 = x0, y0, z0
point1 = x1, y1, z1

dist = math.sqrt((x0-x1)**2+(y0-y1)**2+(z0-z1)**2)

def dist3d((x0, y0, z0), (x1, y1, z1)):
    return math.sqrt((x0-x1)**2+(y0-y1)**2+(z0-z1)**2)
```

i wish to write a optimized loop and store the distance

points = [(472765.09, 6191522.78, 13.0), (472764.82, 6191524.09, 9.0), (472763.8, 6191525.68, 8.0), (472764.07, 6191524.39, 16.0)]

```
dist01 = dist3d(test[0],test[1])
dist02 = dist3d(test[0],test[2])
dist03 = dist3d(test[0],test[2])
dist04 = dist3d(test[0],test[2])

dist12 = dist3d(test[1],test[2])
dist13 = dist3d(test[1],test[3])

dist23 = dist3d(test[2],test[3])

3d_l=[(dist01),(dist02),(dist03),(dist04),(dist12),(dist13),(dist23)]

3d_max =max(3d_l)
3d_min = min(3d_l)
3d_mean =  np.average(3d_l)
```

I wrote the following function (it's not optimized)

```
def dist3d((x0, y0, z0), (x1, y1, z1)):
    return math.sqrt((x0-x1)**2+(y0-y1)**2+(z0-z1)**2)

def dist_3d(obs):
    dist_list = list()
    while len(obs) != 1:
        obs_g = [(obs[0], x) for x in obs[1:]]
        dist_list.append([dist3d(obs_g[i][0], obs_g[i][1]) for i in xrange(len(obs_g))])
        obs.pop(0)
    return dist_list

points = [(472765.09, 6191522.78, 13.0), (472764.82, 6191524.09, 9.0), (472763.8, 6191525.68, 8.0), (472764.07, 6191524.39, 16.0)]
print dist_3d(points)
[[4.217700795331081, 5.922339064664832, 3.554222840244929], [2.1374049685457694, 7.046453008421205], [8.107835716151763]]
```

Comment: What is your question ?

Comment: Yves thanks for your replay. My question is convert these code lines in a (efficient) loop

Comment: Yes, but what is it you can't do ? Such a (double) loop is trivial. By the way, do you want the mean or the median ? This would make a big difference.

Comment: Are you intentionally not including the distance between the first and last point in your calculations?

Comment: I don't see any loop in the accepted solution, your question is still mysterious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't mind using scipy, this is fairly trivial:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.spatial.distance as distance 

points = np.array([(472765.09, 6191522.78, 13.0), (472764.82, 6191524.09, 9.0), (472763.8, 6191525.68, 8.0), (472764.07, 6191524.39, 16.0)])

dist = distance.pdist(points)
print dist.max()
print dist.min()
print np.median(dist)
print np.average(dist)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a generalized version that uses built-in and module functions as much as possible. I don't have`numpy`installed, but if it has a 3-D, or n-D, distance function in it, use that instead of`dist3D()` below.

Actually,`numpy`contains several (other) functions that could be used to speed up some of these immediate calculations. If you're looking for more of an answer based on it, you should indicate this by at least modifying your question's tags.

```
import math
import numpy as np

points = [(472765.09, 6191522.78, 13.0), (472764.82, 6191524.09, 9.0),
          (472763.8, 6191525.68, 8.0), (472764.07, 6191524.39, 16.0)]
points += [points[0]]  # dup first point to include dist from last to first
dist3D = lambda a, b: math.sqrt((a[0]-b[0])**2 + (a[1]-b[1])**2 + (a[2]-b[2])**2)
dists = sorted(dist3D(points[i], points[i+1]) for i in xrange(len(points)-1))
min_dist, max_dist = dists[0], dists[-1]
#mean_dist = sum(dists) / len(dists)
mean_dist = np.average(dists)

print 'min_dist: {:.2f}, mean_dist: {:.2f}, max_dist: {:.2f}'.format(
    min_dist, mean_dist, max_dist)
```

Answer (score -1):

`math.sqrt` is a relatively heavy operation. You can store squares of distances instead, which is enough for finding the minimum, median and maximum, and then get square roots. Further, try finding max and min with a single iteration manually.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I'm confused as to why it wouldn't work for the median.  The middle of a list is still the middle of a list, whether you're getting the square or the square root, as long as you're consistent.  While I'm not saying this answer is correct, your comment (and I'm assuming down vote) isn't really in line, since he is providing a thought process on simplifying the loop, and it's technically answering the question (all-be-it, not well)

Comment: median should be the same yes, average would not. And i'm unsure which OP want's. He's saying median in the text, but using average in the code.

Comment: and meadian in the title (before he silently fixed it). @Jeff: don't worry, I never said it wouldn't work with median; said it wouldn't work with "meadian" (nor with mean)